# SSH Connection reset on IPv6

Tags: ssh, ipv6

When attempting to SSH from an IPv6-enabled host to an IPv6-enabled host, I get:

```
$ ssh remotehost.example.com
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

When I add the `-4` option, all works as expected. I am using keyed SSH, the identity file is correct, there are no firewalls in the way, my home directories are not encrypted. The only problem is with IPv6 - forcing IPv4 makes the connection work perfectly.

The local host is Fedora 22, the remote host is RHEL 6.7. The same symptoms appear going from a RHEL 6.7 host to a RHEL 6.7 host, and from a Fedora 23 host to a RHEL 6.7 host.

The `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file contains the following ListenAddress directives:

```
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
ListenAddress ::
```

What do I need to do to make the IPv6 connection work?

Comment: Check your firewalls?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there are no firewalls in the way, either. I can ssh normally to a different IPv6-enabled host without the `-4` and everything works as expected... so it's something on this particular host, I just can't (yet) tell what.

Comment: Use verbosity? Check the logs on the server?

Comment: The logs simply say "sshd: refused connect from <IPv6addr> (<ipv6addr>).

Comment: Gah. `/etc/hosts.allow`. I thought I'd fixed that... evidently not.

Answer (score 2):

Problem was in not having the source address in `/etc/hosts.allow`.